# Duplicating the <g:tab> element of GWT's TabLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've found the GWT tab panels clunky for the styling I need to do, so I'm trying to make my own, simple tab panel. Basically an HTML5 `<nav>` element for tabs and a `DeckPanel` to display the content. Let the use figure out the rest with CSS3.

The GWT TabLayoutPanel has these "special" tags it uses to define the contents of a tab:

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel>
    <g:tab>
        <g:header>Tab Title</g:header>
        <g:OtherWidget>Tab contents</g:OtherWidget>
    </g:tab>
</g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

I'm referring to `<g:tab>` and `<g:header>`. I see these type of tags used in various places but I have no idea how to create them. Looking at the TabLayoutPanel source, I see that it has an `add` method that expects two widgets, and from that it puts one widget (the contents) into a panel for display and another (the header) into an instance of TabLayoutPanel.Tab. But I have no idea how to duplicate this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use custome tags for you widget like `<g:tab>` and `<g:header>` you need to create a custom ElementParse and register it with the UiBinderWriter. Unfortanatly there is no simple way of doing this yet without editing the sourcecode for gwt.

Usefull links:

[A link to the issue of not being able to create custom ElementParser](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4461)

[TabLayoutPanelParser](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/TabLayoutPanelParser.java&q=TabLayoutPanelParser%20package:http://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)

Comment: Well, that's not really worth it. I suppose I can just use a simple composite container. First child is a header, second is the contents. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In GWT 2.1 there's the [UiChild attribute](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html). It's quite cool.

```
@UiChild public void addTabDef(Widget page, String title) {...}
```

The `title` parameter will be filled with an attribute of the same name in the `tabdef` tag, like so:

```
<v:tabdef title="Tab one"><g:Label>Page one.</g:Label></v:tabdef>
```

**Edit:** to be clear, `tabdef` isn't defined anywhere as a class; the desired behaviour during parsing is defined by UiChild attribute.